# GridviewRow to PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, datagridview, itext

I have a confirmation page,in this page i need to put a grid exactly the same as the page before,this is the grid.

[image]

To create this grid i use this code,the values comes from a session.

```
public void Carrega_valores()
        {
            GridViewRow[] valoresNovos = new GridViewRow[300];
            valoresNovos = (GridViewRow[])Session["vlColunas"];
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Belnr"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Dtemissao"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Dtvenc"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DIASANTEC"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Valor"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VLENCARGOS"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VLFINAL"));
            foreach (GridViewRow grdCount in valoresNovos)
            {
                if (grdCount != null)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr[0] = grdCount.Cells[1].Text;
                    dr[1] = grdCount.Cells[2].Text;
                    dr[2] = grdCount.Cells[3].Text;
                    if(grdCount.Cells[7].Text != "&nbsp;")
                    {
                        dr[3] = grdCount.Cells[7].Text;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr[3] = "";
                    }

                    dr[4] = grdCount.Cells[5].Text;
                    dr[5] = grdCount.Cells[8].Text;
                    dr[6] = grdCount.Cells[5].Text;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
            Session["DataSetValores"] = dt;
            grdSimulacao.DataSource = dt;
            grdSimulacao.DataBind();
        }
```

I need to put in the PDF,i use this code,but its not working.It only create a pdf with the image and text,but the table don't show.

```
public void Gera_Pdf()
        {
            using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream("output.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.None))
            {
                PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(7);

                GridViewRow[] valoresNovos = new GridViewRow[300];
                valoresNovos = (GridViewRow[])Session["vlColunas"];
                foreach (GridViewRow row in valoresNovos)

                {
                        pdfTable.AddCell(row.Cells.ToString());
                }

                var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
                var pdfWriter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);
                document.Open();
                document.Add(pdfTable);
                iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.RegisterDirectory("C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts");
                var font = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 14);
                var font2 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 10);
                var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("Klabin.png");
                image.ScaleToFit(70, 70);
                image.SetAbsolutePosition(25, 780);
                var paragraph = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("DADOS DO ACEITE", font);
                paragraph.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                document.Add(paragraph);
                paragraph = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("Empresa:" + lblEmpresas.Text + " /Representante:" + lblRepresentante.Text + " /CNPJ:" + lblCnpj.Text, font2);
                paragraph.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                document.Add(paragraph);
                var contentByte = pdfWriter.DirectContent;
                contentByte.AddImage(image);

                document.Close();
                byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("output.pdf");
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("myfile.pdf", bytes);
                Session["pdfBytes"] = bytes;
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("output.pdf");
            }
        }
```

Someone know what Am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix,i did this:

```
public void Gera_Pdf()
        {
            using (
                var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream("output.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create,
                    System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.None))
            {
                var font3 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 10);
                DataTable dt = (DataTable) Session["DataSetValores"];
                PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
                PdfPRow row = null;
                float[] widths = new float[] {4f, 4f, 4f, 4f,4f,4f,4f};

                pdfTable.SetWidths(widths);

                pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
                int iCol = 0;
                string colname = "";
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new iText.Phrase("Products"));

                cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;



                    pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase("NF", font3));
                    pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase("Emissão", font3));
                    pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase("Vencimento", font3));
                    pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase("Dias", font3));
                    pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase("Valor(R$)", font3));
                    pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase("Encargos(R$)", font3));
                    pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase("Vlr. Final(R$)", font3));


                foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase(r[0].ToString(), font3));
                        pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase(r[1].ToString(), font3));
                        pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase(r[2].ToString(), font3));
                        pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase(r[3].ToString(), font3));
                        pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase(r[4].ToString(), font3));
                        pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase(r[5].ToString(), font3));
                        pdfTable.AddCell(new iText.Phrase(r[6].ToString(), font3));
                    }

                }
                var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
                    var pdfWriter = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);
                    document.Open();

                    iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.RegisterDirectory("C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts");
                    var font = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 14);
                    var font2 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 10);
                    var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("Klabin.png");
                    image.ScaleToFit(70, 70);
                    image.SetAbsolutePosition(25, 780);
                    var paragraph = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("DADOS DO ACEITE", font);
                    paragraph.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    document.Add(paragraph);
                    paragraph =
                        new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(
                            "Empresa:" + lblEmpresas.Text + " /Representante:" + lblRepresentante.Text + " /CNPJ:" +
                            lblCnpj.Text, font2);
                    paragraph.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                    document.Add(paragraph);
                    var contentByte = pdfWriter.DirectContent;
                    contentByte.AddImage(image);
                paragraph = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("");
                document.Add(paragraph);
                paragraph = new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("");
                paragraph.SpacingAfter = 40f;
                document.Add(paragraph);

                document.Add(pdfTable);
                    document.Close();
                    byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("output.pdf");
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("myfile.pdf", bytes);
                    Session["pdfBytes"] = bytes;
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("output.pdf");
                }
            }
```